# How to hang a chair from the ceiling joists (with attic access)

Tags: ceiling, joists, hanging

I'm planning on hanging a chair from the ceiling. From what I can tell the best method is to add a crosspiece above multiple joists, and mount the chair to that using an eye bolt.

[image: Diagram]

The problem with that is that there is a reasonably large distance between the eye, and the crosspiece.

I can't find a suitable eyebolt (rated to carry a load) that is long enough to cover the space needed. The [longest I've found](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/M12-Long-Shank-Eye-Bolt-Harness-Point-B-S-Standard-400kg-SWL-DK26-/141412783366) is 225mm overall (so about 207mm ceiling to top of beam). I would need one at least 300mm long overall,

Is this a suitable method, and do eye bolts of the required length exist that will carry the load?

Comment: Do you want the chair to swing, or are you thinking it'd be immobile?

Comment: There's eye bolts for just about all situations, you just have to know where to find them. A place to look might be the ones that come on Square-D electrical panel walls. They can easily carry a couple hundred pounds+. I would think you would need threaded rod from the beam to the ceiling, then use a large barrel nut to connect the two with washers, nuts, and a metal plate.

Comment: It would probably be easier to attach a bolt directly to the joist and then hang a carabiner or something.

Comment: Alex - I'd want to be sure it could handle swinging without breaking, just in case.

Comment: Chief - thanks - will look into those, though I was thinking allow for larger person, then double to allow for extra during sitting down, so rate for 400lbs+

Comment: Ratchet - have read that spreading the load across joists is worth doing, which also reduces weakening of the joist by putting a hole through it.

Comment: A quick google search for "industrial eye bolt" brings up plenty of options in any length and strength you could possibly need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a "threaded eye nut" with your strength requirements. (Breaking strength =4000 kg usually translates into safe working load of 400kg.) Use a plain threaded rod (readily available in the length you need) and a good sized metal plate as a washer (I'd suggest 100mm^2, ~6mm thick). From the scale of your drawing, I'm inferring that the board you're using over the joists will cross 4 joists and be fairly substantial.

If you're concerned about a lot of swinging (ie, children), then it might be a good idea to place a wide-ish timber (a 2x8 on this side of the pond; is that a 37x180?) snug between the middle joists and on top of the ceiling with the rod running through. A couple of screws to pin it in place would help.

Comment: Ah I had seen these (plain rods), however I haven't found any that are rated for specific weights, though have found some calling themselves 'high tensile'. I think this, along with addition of something between the joists to stabilise as described (and as shown in @HighTower's diagram) is probably the way to go, assuming I can't locate a long enough eye-bolt.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use an eye bolt! Anyone who swings in the chair, especially in a circular motion, will take the bolt right out of the nut, through the joist, and into the floor. How do I know? Because both of my kids managed to do this with two different hanging chairs.
There is a part which can be described as such:

A steel plate that attaches to the joist through drywall with four bolts. In the center of the plate is a swivel hook, to which you attach a latch.

The swivel part ensures that the swinging motion is localized and doesn't move an eye bolt, allowing it to unscrew itself.

Comment: +1 To clarify: Do the four bolts screw into the bottom of the *one* joist? Or, do the four bolts screw into the bottom of *two* joists? Or, is it two U-bolts that loop over the top of the joist and nothing is screwed into the bottom of the joist? Or, is it four bolts the bolt into a plate that sits on top of the joist?

Answer (score 1):

Would just add more support near the point of the ceiling, that way any swing in the chair will not destroy your ceiling.

otherwise, yes its just a matter of getting a long enough threaded eye. Which you should easily find at a bolt and nut supplier.

[image]

If you are struggling to get a long enough eye. you can use a threaded bar extender (hex coupling)... I think its strong enough, just get two lock nuts to tie on each side. that will allow you to join the bolt to a threaded rod. If you use this method, then you need bolts on the support near the ceiling (ie. on the actual threaded eye) that way it will not free turn and come loose. 
[image]

Your last idea is to get a threaded eye like these. Then once its connected, also use a lock nut to secure it better and drill a hole through the centre and put a split pin to make sure its strong. (you aslo get the shorter ones) 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Finding the part remains the challenge. Online at least ones that are rated for a weight seem to top out at 225mm (that I've found). Additional support definitely a good idea!